# Is it possible to create one APK and run on Android TV and Mobile App?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I created a sample project from  Android Studio. While creating first it asked for Mobile App and I checked TV Project also.
It created two modules in same project with name mobile and tv, both projects contains res,main,values folders respectively.
When I try to run the project I can run any one and it creates separate apk for both.
Is it possible to create one apk and run on both tv and mobile?

Comment: @Robert I am able to create two different apk. I wanted one apk for both Tv and Mobile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's totally possible to have just one APK for both mobile and Android TV. The "trick" is that the mobile launcher activity has in the manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

...while the Android TV activity has this:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

You don't even need any special module configuration, it can just be the same module.

Comment: Thanks I did the changes and able to create in one APK.